# Confusion with duplication of string in C++ language

Tags: c++, string, function, declaration

Everytime I encounter the situation dealing with c string, I'm very confused.

why are those two prints have same result?
In my understaning, first function assigns the address of string at text variable. which seems proper to me. But the second function assigns the address at where text variable points to. what happened here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void getText(char** text) {
    *text = strdup("AAAAA");
}
void getText2(char* text) {
    text = strdup("AAAAA");
}

int main()
{
    char* text;

    getText(&text);
    std::cout << text << std::endl; // prints "AAAAA"

    getText2(text);
    std::cout << text << std::endl; // prints "AAAAA"
}
```

Comment: This is not C.. This confusion should be cleared first.

Comment: Just don't use c-strings in c++, and you will never have problems.

Comment: The second function doesn't modify the `char* text` from `main`

Comment: Check this example out: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87e2070b354a7f4e

Comment: The second function passes the pointer by value, not reference. You're only modifying the local variable, not the variable in `main()`.

Comment: Change the text in getText2 to "BBBBB" to see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function

```
void getText2(char* text) {
    text = strdup("AAAAA");
}
```

has a memory leak.

Function parameters are function local variables.

You can imagine the definition of the function getText2 and its call the following way. I renamed the function parameter that it would be more clear.

```
getText2(text);

//...

void getText2( /*char* parm_text */) {
    char *parm_text = text;
    parm_text = strdup("AAAAA");
}
```

The local variable that is the parameter `parm_text` will be destroyed after exiting the function. However the allocated memory in this statement

```
    parm_text = strdup("AAAAA");
```

is not freed.

On the other hand the argument itself was not changed. The function used the value stored in the argument that was assigned to the local variable.

You could declare the parameter as reference to the argument. For example

```
void getText2(char* &text) {
                    ^^^^^
    text = strdup("AAAAA");
}
```

In this case it is the argument itself that is changed in the function.

As for the function

```
void getText(char** text) {
    *text = strdup("AAAAA");
}
```

then the argument is passed indirectly by using a pointer to the argument. So inside the function the value of the argument is changed.

Comment: Thank you vlad. Opinion about memory leak was very useful.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you passed a pointer to your local pointer, you dereference that pointer and make it point to the value returned by `strdup()`, you are modifying the address the original pointer points to.

In the second one, you pass the poiner itself, you cannot alter it inside the function because even if the two pointers point to the same memory initially, they are stored in different places, so altering the address of one doesn't affect the other.

If you alter the data the pointer points to, and not the address in `getText2()` then it will change, like

```
text[0] = 'B';
text[1] = 'B';
text[2] = 'B';
text[3] = 'B';
text[4] = 'B';
```

You should also call `free()` after you use the pointer returned by `strdup()` or it will be a memory leak.

Finally, using pointers in c++ is currently considered bad practice unless you are a library programmer, which I don't think is the case. Instead, use `std::string` and all the c++ concepts (*like pass by reference which doesn't exist in c*) that will allow you to write modern c++ programs.

Passing by reference in c++ is possible

```
void getText(std::string &text)
{
    text = "AAAAAA";
}

void getText2(std::string &text)
{
   text = "BBBBBB";
}

int main()
{
    std::string text;
    getText(text);
    std::cout << text << std::endl;
    getText2(text);
    std::cout << text << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There you go, no memory leaks, it works as expected, and it's modern c++.

Comment: To make it "real" C++ it should be `std::string getText()`